# Django views passing in unicode name instead of string to url

Tags: python, html, regex, django, strip

I have a simple personal Django project which allows someone to create a message by providing the username and message on the index page. They can then see all the messages by a given user through that link in the database.

The issue I'm facing right now is a

`NoReverseMatch Error "Reverrse for 'messages' with arguments '(u'josh',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['messages/(?P<user_name>\\d+)?/']`

where '(u'josh',)' is the user.name returned by:

```
        <li><a href="{% url 'messages' user.name %}">{{ user.name }}</a></li>
```

How do I strip the excess of off that so that only 'josh' is returned (which is what I'm assuming this URL wants). I want to do this in the HTML file itself.

```
url(r'^messages/(?P<user_name>\d+)?/', views.view_messages, name='messages'),
```

Models

```
class User (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):              
        return self.name

class Message (models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=140, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):              
        return self.content
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` then `{{ user.name }}` shouldn't return anything. I assume that you use a custom user model. If yes then you can just user `{{ user.name.0 }}` to get the first member of the tuple.

If instead you *are* using the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` then just try `{{ user.username }}` to just get the username.

*Update*: Hmmm then restore your template again to `{{ user.name }}` and change your url pattern to

```
url(r'^messages/(?P<user_name>\w+)?/', views.view_messages, name='messages'),
```

(notice the `\w+` instead of the `\d+`: `\d` is for digits, `\w` is for characters. That's why you didn't get a match).

Comment: I've edited the post with the respective custom models. user.name.0 gives me '(u'j',)' instead of josh

Answer (score 1):

I think that the trouble is because of `user_name` is named parameter in url, so you can trying pass like named parameter

```
{% url 'messages' user_name=user.name %}
```

And of course you must use `\w+` for the matching.

Comment: You don't really need to put the ``user_name`` kwarg for the ``{% url %}`` to work. It works either way even though it was defined with a named parameter. I always use named parameters in my urls, like ``(?P<pk>\d+)`` but out of habit I always forget to also use them with the ``{% url %}`` and just pass the parameters as ``args``. After all you better not have more than two or three parameters in a url :)

Answer (score 0):

django uses a separate model field for directly displaying in the URL: SlugField
"Slug is a newspaper term. A slug is a short label for something, containing only letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens. They’re generally used in URLs."

so either you update your model with a name_slug or just use "encoding", e.g. base64